# Liveness probe failed: OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: EOF: unknown

Tags: kubernetes, containers

pod failed to startup once. What could be the reason? container started later than LivenessProbe had been activated?

liveness probe configured as:

```
livenessProbe:
    exec:
      command:
      - /usr/bin/commandA
      - --is-alive
    initialDelaySeconds: 5
    periodSeconds: 2
    successThreshold: 1
    failureThreshold: 3
```

---

Error logs from pod

```
$ kubectl describe po t1004-rcpsdl-79c455547b-kdtvk -n cran1

Containers:
xxxxxx:
......
Port: <none>
Host Port: <none>
State: Running
Started: Fri, 03 Jul 2020 06:01:26 +0000
Last State: Terminated
Reason: Error
Exit Code: 1
Started: Fri, 03 Jul 2020 06:00:45 +0000
Finished: Fri, 03 Jul 2020 06:01:25 +0000
Ready: True
Restart Count: 1

Events:
Type Reason Age From Message
---- ------ ---- ---- -------
Normal Scheduled <unknown> default-scheduler Successfully assigned cran1/t1004-rcpsdl-79c455547b-kdtvk to controller-0
Normal Pulled 105m (x2 over 106m) kubelet, controller-0 Container image "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" already present on machine
Normal Created 105m (x2 over 106m) kubelet, controller-0 Created container rcpsdl
Normal Started 105m (x2 over 106m) kubelet, controller-0 Started container rcpsdl
Warning Unhealthy 92m kubelet, controller-0 Liveness probe failed: OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: EOF: unknown
```

Comment: check kubelet logs on the node where the pod got scheduled

Comment: Do you have any other pod running ? The error come from the runtime , can you check the logs of the nodes (from kubernentes and on the system) ? And which container runtime are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing time interval of these parameters

```
initialDelaySeconds: 300
periodSeconds: 10
successThreshold: 1
failureThreshold: 5
```

Reference : [Original Post](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041796991-How-to-Troubleshoot-and-Address-Liveness-Readiness-probe-failure)

Hoping it will work for you.